# How to invoke an action in the current router from the child component in Ember Octane?

Tags: ember.js, ember-octane

I am working with Ember Octane version, I want to invoke an action in the `Route` from the child component. The pseudo code is as follows.

```js
**Route**
export default class SomeRouter extends Route {    
    model() {
        return data;        
    }
    @action
    refreshRoute() {
        this.refresh();
    }
}

**SomerRouter.hbs** 

<ChildComponent> //Using child component here

**ChildComponent**
export default class ChildComponent extends Component { 
    @action
    revert() {
       //How do I invoke the "refreshRoute" on the SomeRouter from here?
    }
}
```

In the revert method of the above child component, "this" refers to the component itself but in the previous version of the ember "this" refers to the router where I could simply call this.refresh(). So how do I achieve this in Ember Octane. Would really appreciate any help.

Comment: be careful: what you name `Router` is the `Route`. The `Router` is either the ember internal, well, `Router`, or the `router.js` where you configure this router.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You dont. This is actually one of the things that are still a bit inconsistent even with octane. Because the bound context of the route template is the `Controller`, not the route. So you can not access the action with `{{this.refreshRoute}}`.

To call an action on the `Route` your best way is to uzilize [`send`](https://api.emberjs.com/ember/3.15/classes/Route/methods/send?anchor=send). But to do this you need a Controller and define a different action on the Controller:

**controllers/some.js**:

```
export default class SomeController extends Controller {
  @action
  refreshRouteFromController() {
    this.send('refreshRoute');
  }
}
```

Now this function you can use from your template:

```
<ChildComponent @refresh={{this.refreshRouteFromController}}>
```

And then use it from your component:

```
revert() {
   this.args.refresh();
}
```

Or directly from a button:

```
<button {{on "click @refresh}}>...</button>
```

Comment: Thanks. I implemented the solution your way. It worked.